# How to sort OrderedDict using a sorted list of keys?

Tags: python, sorting

Suppose I have a `collections.OrderedDict` object and a re-arranged list of its keys:

```
ordereddict = collections.OrderedDict((
    ('key_78', 'value'),
    ('key_40', 'value'),
    ('key_96', 'value'),
    ('key_53', 'value'),
    ('key_04', 'value'),
    ('key_89', 'value'),
    ('key_52', 'value'),
    ('key_86', 'value'),
    ('key_16', 'value'),
    ('key_63', 'value'),
))

# Example only; actual list will **not** == sorted(ordereddict)
key_list = ['key_04', 'key_16', 'key_40', 'key_52', 'key_53', 'key_63', 'key_78', 'key_86', 'key_89', 'key_96']
```

How can I sort the `OrderedDict` so that it is ordered in the same way as the `key_list`?

Comment: Is there any reason to avoid creating a _new_ ordereddict?  Because that's easy ...

Comment: why do you want a list of keys to sort the keys, why not just sort the keys themselves?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the following:

```
def sort_by_list(dict_, list_):
    for key in list_:
        dict_.move_to_end(key)

sort_by_list(ordereddict, key_list)
```

This only works if the `list_` contains all the keys in the dict, and on Python 3.2 or later.

Answer (score 11):

Just create a new OrderedDict:

```
newdct = OrderedDict((key, olddct[key]) for key in sortedlist)
```

If you really need this to happen *in place*, you can clear the olddct and update it with the new one:

```
olddct.clear()
olddct.update(newdct)
```

Comment: I tested the performance (with `timeit`), and my method was 2-4 times faster. Apart from that, modifying the dict in place is also more suited to its use in my program.

Comment: @minerz029 Your method requires Python 3, though.

Comment: @user4815162342: I'm using Python 3.3, but I'll add a note to my answer.

Comment: @minerz029 -- Also, what exactly did you time?  Did you time just creating a new dict or also clearing the old and updating it?  In general, you probably don't _need_ do steps 2 and 3 and I would argue that the code is more clear which is worth spending a few extra microseconds on :-)