# Sorting a matrix by one of its fields, given a list with sorted values

Tags: python, list, sorting

I need to join a list and a matrix using python.

The matrix/2d list holds column definitions - column name and datatype. The data is not ordered by the right column positions.

Example:

```
(Pdb) colmnAndDatatypeMatrix

[('col_b', 'number') , ('col_a','varchar')]
```

The list contains only the column names but it is ordered correctly, which is very important for me.

Example:

```
(Pdb) colmnList
['col_a', 'col_b']
```

What I want to perform:

I want to order the matrix/2d list so it will be ordered exactly like the list. The list and matrix, of course,  hold the names of the same columns.

If it was SQL I would just join the two and query the column names from the list (so that the order is kept) and the type from the joined 2d array.

How can I perform this in python?

Comment: Are you using numpy matrices?

Comment: @Daenyth no, just regular python lists

Comment: What criteria you use for ordering the list?

Comment: So, you want to sort the list of tuples based on the list with the given column names?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the key param of the standar function sorted (available since Python 2.4):

```
matrix = [('col_b', 'number') , ('col_a','varchar')]
colmnList = ['col_a', 'col_b']

# Sort the matrix using as creiteria the position of the element in colmnList
sorted_matrix = sorted(matrix, key = lambda item: colmnList.index(item[0]))

print(matrix)
print(sorted_matrix)

>>> [('col_b', 'number'), ('col_a', 'varchar')]
>>> [('col_a', 'varchar'), ('col_b', 'number')]
```

Ref: [Sorting Mini-HOW TO, Key functions](https://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions)

---

Old answer

Going simple, it might be fancier solutions but this solve your problem for sure, just create another matrix using the `colmnList`.

```
matrix = [('col_b', 'number') , ('col_a','varchar')]
colmnList = ['col_a', 'col_b']

ordered_matrix = []

for col_name in colmnList:
    for elem in matrix:
        if elem[0] == col_name:
            ordered_matrix.append(elem)
            break # There is no need to iterate again here.


print(matrix)
print(ordered_matrix)

>>> [('col_b', 'number'), ('col_a', 'varchar')]
>>> [('col_a', 'varchar'), ('col_b', 'number')]
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Not very efficient, but surely does the job.

Comment: @golosovsky, take a look again to the answer, I think you realy could use that technique.

Answer (score 2):

As a quick workaround using [`OrderedDicts`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) I would suggest the following:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

# list of tuples (what you called matrix)
m = [('col_b', 'number') , ('col_a','varchar')]

# list with ordered keys (will be used for sorting)
l = ['col_a', 'col_b']

# create OrderedDict from list `m`
od = OrderedDict(m)

# define a function to order the keys of an OrderedDict by a given list
def sort_by_list(d, l):
    for key in l:
        d.move_to_end(key)

# call function defined above in order to sort keys of OrderedDict `od` by list `l`
sort_by_list(od, l)

# print OrderedDict after we sorted the keys
print(od)

# print sorted list/matrix after sorting using workaround with OrderedDict
sorted = list(od.items())
print(sorted)
```

Please keep in mind that this approach works only with Python 3.2 and above and is based on this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23587175/3991125).

Comment: thanks for the answer! The only problem is that I'm using python 2.7

Comment: So you might want to take a look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/35295081/3991125) below.